# How do I write a QuickCheck property that arbitrarily modifies its arbitrary input?

Tags: haskell, testing

Suppose I want to verify [`isSubsequenceOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isSubsequenceOf). I then need to generate some `xs`, and then generate `ys` out of them by *arbitrarily* adding or removing some elements. Then I could verify the property for all the pairs thus obtained. Using [sublistOf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:sublistOf), I would go like this:

```
\xs -> sublistOf xs `isSubsequenceOf` xs
```

— Except that this does not type check.

Unfortunately I don't understand the design of the QuickCheck library overall, and even such seemingly trivial cases puzzle me a big deal. Do I have to spell out a full-blown monadic device of type `Gen Result`? It kind of defies the purpose of the abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to spell out a full-blown monadic device of type Gen Result?

What is a "full-blown monadic device"?  Yes, you should probably use the `Gen` monad but it isn't hard and there is a Testable instance for you to use:

```
mytest :: [Int] -> Gen Bool
mytest xs = do ys <- sublistOf xs
               pure $ ys `isSubsequenceOf` xs
  where isSubsequenceOf _ _ = True
```

And the use:

```
*Main> quickCheck mytest
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant. As the property should hold for any `xs`, I meant it to be arbitrary as well. This is not important to the spirit of the answer though, just a minor detail.

Comment: I'm confused as to what else you want to be arbitrary.  Do you understand how to write your property now or not?

Comment: Let me fix the previous comment: read as "I meant `xs` to be arbitrary as well". I do understand how to write my property, though I am a bit disappointed there is no clever combination of combinators to solve this in one line.

Comment: You can pretty much always code golf things into a one liner.  `mytest xs = flip isSubsequenceOf xs <$> sublistOf xs`, for example.

Comment: @Kindaro But `xs` *is* arbitrary. In particular, `quickCheck mytest` proceeds by calling `arbitrary` and passing its result as `xs` to `mytest`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Oh. This is revealing.

Comment: Thank you @DanielWagner, I was thinking I must be densely missing the question.